# Ionic app how key and value storage works

Tags: sqlite, calendar, ionic3, storage, key-value

So I am trying to make a calendar app in ionic and I want to store events, if a user makes one, I looked at the ionic documentation, and it makes it seem too simple I basically copied exactly what they have with a few adjustments and I do not know how to test it. Here is what I have:

```
save() { 
    var n = 0
    this.event.startTime = new Date(this.readDescription())
    this.storage.set('fooditem'+this.increaseVal(),this.event);
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss({event: this.event})

    
  }
```

increaseVal() function just increments the key name so I have a new key for every new value (this is a temporary fix)
I know I probably need to get the data stored after it has been saved but I just need to make sure it actually saves

Comment: What's your question ? How do you know the value has been saved ? By fetching it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this question with the assumption that you want to know where the data is being stored & to see the value at that location.

Ionic Storage gives options to use SQLite, IndexedDB, WebSQL and localstorage as ways to store data on the device. With the first 3, there is no way to access the data besides fetching it. Local Storage however, is accessible in Chrome Dev Tools > Application > Local Storage

Ionic Storage allows the developer to configure the driver used to store data by specifying it in the driverOrder options in App Module. Simply put localstorage as the first value in this as such `driverOrder: ['localstorage', 'indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']` to force the app to store data in localstorage and then you can see the value stored in the location described above.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation, and will definitely help me test out my storage

Comment: I had faced this same query a while ago, which is why I was able to connect the dots and explain it such. Glad I could be of help.